# display edit box when hover the picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Soory if I didn't show you all the code, because I am not sure how to implement it, what I try to do is that suppose this is a picture following:

```
  #photo{ width:100px;height:120px;}
  <div id="photo"><img src="myphoto.jpg"/></div>
```

and I have edit photo box:

```
   #edit{width:60px;height:30px;background:#000000;color:#ffffff}
  <div id="edit">edit it</div>
```

When I hover the image,  i want the edit phot box display in the top right corner of the image, and when the cursor move out of the image, it will be disappeared.

So I assume using the following

```
     $("#photo img").hover(function() {
    $("#edit").fadein();
 }, function() {
    $("#edit").hide();
    });
```

any one could help me with it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's basically it. You also need to (a) hide the #edit element on load using `display:none` in your stylesheet, (b) change `fadein` to `fadeIn` (capital I), and probably (c) position the #edit element absolutely inside the #photo div so it doesn't reflow the page when it appears and disappears.

**update:** Oh, and (d) add a mouseover to the #edit element so that moving the mouse over it doesn't register as a mouseout of the image:

```
$("#edit").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/bNmAd/2/

Comment: thanks, but how to position it to the top right corner of the image?

Comment: Add `right: 0;` to the #edit element and `position: relative;` to the #photo element: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/bNmAd/3/